# How to use Pandas to replace column entries in DataFrame and create dictionary new-old values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a file which contains data as the following:

```
x y
z w
a b
a x
w y
```

I want to create a file with the following replacements dictionary, which has a unique replacement number for each string that is determined by the the order in which strings first appear in the file, when read left-to-right and top to bottom (note that this should be created, it is not supplied):

```
{'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3, 'w':4 , 'a':5, 'b':6}
```

and the output file would be:

```
1 2
3 3
5 6
5 1
4 2
```

Is there any efficient way to create both the processed file and the dictionary with Pandas?

I thought of creating the dictionary in the following policy:

```
_counter = 0
def counter():
    global _counter
    _counter += 1
    return _counter
replacements_dict = collections.defaultdict(counter)
```

Comment: How do you derive the dictionary? If it's an input, you can't get more efficient than `d = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3, 'w':4, 'a':5, 'b':6}`.

Comment: How is Pandas going to create that dictionary? It looks like you defined the replacements yourself.

Comment: Do you mean the dictionary is created by collecting rows, puting together, and discarding repeated elements?

Comment: Hi I added the code which can help creating the dictionary. Yes the dictionary should be created on the flight and not hardcoded.

Comment: I cannot see any pattern in the resulting dict. The values look arbitrary.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes they are pretty arbitrary. Only the order has influence on the values

Comment: So the replacement number is the order in which letters first appear in the file, when read left-to-right and top to bottom. Please remember we're not familiar with your problem so your requirements need to be clear. I'm trying to connect dots.

Comment: @roganjosh Right. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) with `MultiIndex Series` created  by[`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and last write to file by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\s+", header=None)

print (df)
   0  1
0  x  y
1  z  w
2  a  b
3  a  x
4  w  y

s = df.stack()
fact = pd.factorize(s)

#indexing is necessary
d = dict(zip(fact[1].values[fact[0]], fact[0] + 1))
print (d)
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'w': 4, 'a': 5, 'b': 6}
```

For new file:

```
#values splited by ,
pd.Series(d).to_csv('dict.csv')
#read Series from file, convert to dict
d = pd.read_csv('dict.csv', index_col=[0], squeeze=True, header=None).to_dict()
print (d)
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'w': 4, 'a': 5, 'b': 6}

df = pd.Series(fact[0] + 1, index=s.index).unstack()
print (df)

   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  5  1
4  4  2

df.to_csv('out', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd like to create the dictionary on the flight, see my edited question

Comment: @Codevan - So need replace values by their counts? If yes, check second answer.

Comment: @jezrael I managed to work it out in my last comment under the question. The replacement value in the dictionary is based on the order of the letters in the file when reading it left to right and top to bottom. `x` is the first encountered letter, then `y`, then `z`, then `w` etc.

Comment: @roganjosh - Ya, it was really unclear before your comment.

Comment: @jezrael But now how do I get or save in another file the replacement dictionary itself?

Comment: @Codevan - Added solution for dict, for write dictionary to file and for read this file to dictionary again.

Comment: @jezrael I found a bug in your code. check the dictionary created by the following example:
x y\n
w x\n
z w\n
a b\n
a x\n
w y\n

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want dictionary `d` in such a way that values assigned to keys correspond to the keys appearance, in rows:

```
d={'col1':['x', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'w'], 'col2':['z','w','b','x','y']}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    x    z
1    y    w
2    a    b
3    a    x
4    w    y
```

=================================

Using **itertools**:

```
import itertools
raw_list = list(itertools.chain(*[df.iloc[i].tolist() for i in range(df.shape[0])]))
d=dict()
counter=1
for k in raw_list:
    try: 
        _=d[k]
    except:
        d[k]=counter
        counter+=1
```

then:

```
d
```

Output:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'w': 4, 'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': 2}
```

I hope it helps!

===========================================

Using **factorize**:

```
s = df.stack()
d=dict{}
for (x,y) in zip(pd.factorize(s)[1], pd.factorize(s)[0]+1):
    d[x]=y
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think there is no way to do that with the factorize using the upper guy's answer?